# ErrorException in Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

it's my first time making a log in laravel. I followed the steps here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication.
But this error comes out:
[image]

I'm really confused what this error is about since I'm new to laravel?
Here is my controller code:

```
 public function login()
{
    $admins = Admin::all();
    $validator = \Validator::make($admins , ['username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required']);
    if ($validator->passes())
    {
        $userdata = array(
            'username' => Admin::get('username'),
            'password' => Admin::get('password'));
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata))
        {
            echo 'Success';
        }
        else {
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::resource('Admins','AdminController');
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'AdminController@login'));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the problem ,

```
$admins = Admin::all();
$validator = \Validator::make($admins , ['username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required']);
```

replace it with :

```
$inputs = Input::all();
$validator = \Validator::make($inputs , ['username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required']);
```

and don't forget to change : thanks goes to [FatBoyXPC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5373991/fatboyxpc)

```
$userdata = array(
            'username' => Admin::get('username'),
            'password' => Admin::get('password'));
```

with :

```
$userdata = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'));
```

Comment: You should change `Admin::get()` to `Input::get()`, too.

Comment: Oh so input::all() is not the name of the model? I thought that was the case so that's why I changed it. I'll try now

Comment: take care of the important note that @FatBoyXPC mentioned :)

Comment: `Input` is the name of the Input Facade. You can also get the input using the `request()` helper. You can read about request input here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

The reason you are confused here is because `Input::all()` will get you an array of all the inputs, whereas `Model::all()` will get you a collection containing all of the records of that model from the database.